# Sofer wearing a special robe

Tags: minhag, clothing, safrus

In the book “Israel: Splendors of the Holy Land” by Sara Kochav, there is a picture of a sofer (Torah scibe). The image describtion claims that the sofer needs to wear a special robe, as depicted in the picture. Does anyone know where does this robe and tradition come from?

[image]

Comment: Hi Shimon, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for this question!

Comment: none of the images I looked at of people writing scrolls has anyone wearing anything similar to this.

Comment: Can you post the "image description" in English that you mention, please?  It seems logical that there is a minhag somewhere of special scribal attire. Priests had special clothing.  Ezra was a scribe as well as priest - maybe some parts of a priestly/scribal attire tradition were maintained down through the ages(??).  It's a special activity - I doubt there's a picture of a sofer writing a Torah wearing a "We want Moshiach NOW" T-shirt.

Comment: @Gary I wouldn't be the least surprised if I saw a picture of a Lubavitcher wearing such a t-shirt while writing a Torah - but that wouldn't make it a tradition.

Comment: @Oliver   Well, in this question - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3647/what-determines-a-minhag?noredirect=1&lq=1 , there's a comment from our..least critical member(who I DO respect an awful lot for his efforts to make this a more concise place)..saying:  "minhag is whatever people do and these can change at any time." ..so it's pretty much poskened, at least around here :)

Comment: @Gary Then I sincerely hope halachah and/or minhag don't turn into a state of anarchy around here. (A "more concise place"?)

Comment: @Oliver - Yes, more concise - I know this place takes a lot of effort by too few folks to avoid anarchy. Just trying to be relatively nice, and not overdo it and get banned or cheremed or whatever they do here.  Gotta wait 'til Purim Torah before temporarily changing my name to  QuadrupleZZZZ and commenting to most questions asked with "Why do you want to know that?  Who cares about such a thing? What makes you think somebody else cares about that? Who do you think you are, anyhow? Oh, you're not a veteran?  Then maybe you should have read the rules and known how to better ask that, Rashi" :)

Answer (score 2):

So that the ink stains should not soil his shirt sleeves.

Comment: Source? Logic. (Full circle; nice.)

Comment: Why would that be a reason "that the sofer needs to wear a special robe"? That would be a reason why it's practical to where a robe.

Comment: Unless you are assuming that the sofer is a talmid chacham and thus liable to death if he wears a stained shirt.

Comment: The robe looks very distinctive (traditional or ethnic) for a smock. Also, why would he choose a white protective garmet, one that leaves the bottom of his shirt sleeves uncovered?

Comment: Wouldn't black be a much better color for a garment that's supposed to take in ink stains?

Comment: If he wears a black smock, he might not notice he is inky and wipe on something.