# Is it obligatory to eliminate a mistaken custom?

Tags: minhag, halacha-theory, mistakes

Are there any halachic authorities who indicate that it is not just permissible to ignore a mistaken custom (minhag ta'ut) but actually obligatory to eliminate such a custom?

Comment: Are you assuming it doesn't lead to any problematic consequences? For instance, a custom to murder 15 year olds, is to my mind mistaken and ignoring it would be a big problem because of the murder.

Comment: Probably depends on the cost/benefit ...

Comment: Is this the same question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/when-is-a-minhag-no-longer-a-minhag?rq=1